# ¿Cómo eliminar filas o datos de forma que pueda hacer un rollback en caso de error?

Tags: sql, microsoft

Tengo una base de datos y vamos a empezar a eliminar algunas filas que no forman parte de la información. La pregunta es que si yo ejecuto un `delete from "nombre_tabla"`  y me "equivocará" no tengo como hacer un rollback y deshacer los cambios.

¿Cómo podría ejecutar una transacción de forma que si elimino algún dato pueda volver atrás con un rollback? Si alguien pudiese ayudarme estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La pregunta es muy, pero que muy amplia. Voy a intentar desmenuzarla un poco, al menos para que tengas una idea de lo que solicitas.

***Escenario:***

```
Create table voyABorrar (id int primary key, valor varchar(10));
go
Insert into voyABorrar(id, valor )
values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c');
go
```

Si en una **transacción**, no hay **commit**, y la he definido, puedo hacer un **rollback**, sin problemas.

[image: Res]

La sentencia está ejecutada con un `Begin tran`. Pero no hay un `commit tran`, ni un `rollback tran`

En otra sesión:

[image: Registro borrado]

Ahora en la sesión 1 hago un `rollback tran`.

[image: Rollback]

Y en la sesión 2, sin el `hint with (NoLock)`, hago un `select` y la sentencia de borrado no se ha aplicado.

[image: Resultado]

Resultado= los borrados no se aplican hasta que la transacción no se ha confirmado. Por defecto sino se establece una transacción, esta se ejecuta implícitamente, por tanto cuando termina de realizar el borrado, los registros han desaparecido, y no se pueden borrar.

Existen alternativas, muchas y variadas, algunas en función de la versión de `Sql Server` que tengas.

Muchas opciones:

- Puedes utilizar una tabla temporal '##'
- Puedes hacer un select into e insertar en una tabla secundaria, para disponer de los datos mientras confirmas que el borrado es apropiado.
- Puedes utilizar la clausula output e insertarlos en una variable de tabla
- Puedes utilizar una versionado de tabla a modo de histórico, y eliminar de la original, manteniendo los registros al menos durante un tiempo en esta.

Hay un montón de posibilidades. Y otras cuantas que podrían aparecer en función de las necesidades. Pero tienen que tener una mayor definición

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias por compartir tus conocimientos!

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Sólo quiero aportar que la tabla temporal que sugieres será global y se eliminará cuando los usuarios que referencian esa tabla se desconecten. La desventaja de crear una tabla back up es el tamaño; si la tabla tiene cientos de millones de registros o más, puede ser algo pesado. Siempre hay tradeoffs. +1